# Any alternatives to send free send SMS alert using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, sms

I have developed some monitoring job with google apps script, the SMS alert will be sent to my mobile via Calender event as shown in here ( https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45351?hl=en ).  So that I can receive the alert even without data connection in oversea.

However, Google is going to stop the SMS notification for calender event, it seems that my monitoring job cannot send SMS alert after June 27th.

Is it possible to send free SMS alert to my mobile using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to have your script email your phone number directly. Most carriers allow you to send emails to your phone via text message. A quick search found [this helpful page](http://solutions.csueastbay.edu/questions.php?questionid=348). Find whatever syntax your phone carrier uses, or, if it isn't listed, do a quick search for "text phone from email" with your carrier listed in the search. I sent a quick test message from my Gmail to my phone and it worked just fine.

Comment: I don't know if there has such service in my country.  I will try to see if this service in provided by my mobile network carriers.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Too bad, there does not have free sms gateway in my country.  The email to sms service from csl does not work also (I'm using the mobile service from csl already).